# Approach for dealing with generated Token with expiration Time

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, token

I have a scenario where I send invites to random email Id's(which may be a registered user's email ID or non registered). Now the mail is sent with a link which will direct them to the application and to a specific page. Before sending invite I must assign a token to each mail Id's and set a expiration time for it. Now my doubt is should I save the tokens for each email Id's in DB? If not what other options are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: save the tokens in DB; purge those that time-out every now and then so you don't stuff your DB.

Option 2: encrypt data (including creation time) into the token.

(Option 3: do not send spam emails to random people who do not sign up for your service. ;) )

Comment: could you please elaborate on this `purge those that time-out every now and then so you don't stuff your DB.` line

Comment: Something like `DELETE FROM tokens WHERE created_at > DATEADD(minute, -30, GETDATE())` or similar depending on the dialect, run every time you do any processing, with an index on `created_at`, shouldn't hardly take up any time at all. Or periodically every 15 minutes, or whatever you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will follow this approach now :)